# Fork-join: fork all subtasks or leave one for the current thread

Tags: java, fork-join

I'm trying to understand the details of how the fork-join works.

Wikipedia has the following example for merge-sort where the left half is forked and the right half is processed by the current thread.

```
mergesort(A, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:                     // at least one element of input
        mid = ⌊(hi - lo) / 2⌋
        fork mergesort(A, lo, mid)  // process (potentially) in parallel with main task
        mergesort(A, mid, hi)       // main task handles second recursion
        join
        merge(A, lo, mid, hi)
```

However most Java examples I've seen fork **all** subtasks and wait for their results:

```
for (Document document : folder.getDocuments()) {
    DocumentSearchTask task = new DocumentSearchTask(document, searchedWord);
    forks.add(task);
    task.fork();
}
for (RecursiveTask<Long> task : forks) {
    count = count + task.join();
}
return count;
```

The Wikipedia example makes more sense to me, because a thread will do something useful instead of blocking and waiting for subtasks.

On the other hand, if we fork all tasks, we avoid recursion and can't get `StackOverflowError`.

What is a preferred way to split a task and why?

Comment: So whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the preferred way is to fork and treat all subtasks the same way. Here are a few reasons:

1. `ForkJoinPool` in Java implements `ExecutorService`. Notice that all methods in `ExecutorService` are *asynchronous*. There is a reason for that - you can often spawn some computation in the background asynchronously while your main thread can do some other useful work until before it needs the result of the computation, e.g. spawn more asynchronous tasks.
2. It's easier to reason about. Code often looks cleaner if you treat all subproblems the same way rather then introducing a certain asymmetry to the task.
3. Not forking and doing part of the computation on the main thread doesn't really have any advantage. If you fork all tasks and then wait for join, your main thread is in a waiting state and consumes almost no resources and the worker threads can fully utilize the processor.

It's more a matter of preference rather than a strict choice, though. Except for the potential stack overflow you mentioned, they are functionally equivalent.

I cannot speak for the Wikipedia author, but my guess is that she was either trying to keep things simple for explanation, or she had a background in less abstract languages where forking/joining is not as simple as in Java.

---

*Update:* Regarding too many threads blocking, this is not a concern with `ForkJoinPool`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26576260/2032064), the special thing about `ForkJoinPool` is that work stealing really does occur inside the `join` call.

Comment: My concern was that there will be high number of threads blocked waiting. But Doug Lea's paper on fork-join says "When a worker thread encounters a join operation, it processes other tasks, if available, until the target task is noticed to have completed (via isDone)". So, I guess forking all subtasks is a better consistent way.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer with a link that may be of interest. I've also implicitly assumed that the `join` in both versions is the ForkJoinPool join. Other synchronization would really be blocking, only ForkJoinPool is special.